# How to act on each values of the Slider control?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I added a Slider control in a Windows Phone app 8.1

The control contains 5 values. How do I act on them?

It acts by using c # or XAML?

My Slider is this:

```
<Slider Header="Imposta difficoltà" x:Name="SliderDifficolta"  TickFrequency="1" StepFrequency="1" TickPlacement="Inline" Minimum="1" Maximum="5" Margin="0,190,0,251" Background="#FFD4BB18" LargeChange="10" Value="3" Foreground="#FFF8610B" SmallChange="0"  />
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve the desired results? What did not work?

Comment: Didn't know about the property ValueChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle `ValueChanged` event.
First you need to add handler (`ValueChanged="ValueChangedHandler"`) to the XAML markup:

```
<Slider Header="Imposta difficoltà" x:Name="SliderDifficolta"  TickFrequency="1" StepFrequency="1" TickPlacement="Inline" Minimum="1" Maximum="5" Margin="0,190,0,251" Background="#FFD4BB18" LargeChange="10" Value="3" Foreground="#FFF8610B" SmallChange="0" ValueChanged="ValueChangedHandler" />
```

Then you write down the event handler in your code-behind:

```
private void ValueChangedHandler(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = String.Format("Current value: {0}", e.NewValue);
    this.textBlock1.Text = msg;
}
```